# Fix issues with composer.lock and composer.json updatation

Tags: magento2, composer

I am having issue of installing extension from CLI and it displays auto-load error of one past extension and says it's already defined.

> ie: Autoload error:  Module 'Mageplaza_Core' from
>   '/vendor/mageplaza/module-core' has been already defined in
>   'vendor/mageplaza/core-m2

'

I have checked `composer.json` and deleted extension lines from there but still  creating the same issue.

I think these issues can be fixed from `composer.json` or `composer.lock`.  I am not sure should I update `composer.lock`  or `composer.json`?

Comment: Check registration.php file of both module, there have to different module name in this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't update the composer.lock manually because this one is automatically generated. You can add modules in your composer.json there in the require and then run the following composer command:

```
composer update
```

Then you can track the changes through git because besides your composer.json the composer.lock will be automatically updated and pull them to your live or staging environment. After the pull you should run the command

```
composer install --no-dev
```

If you use composer install it will only install the versions as given in the composer.lock and if you use composer update it will try to update to the latest version as possible based on the composer versioning.